# How to query a table but ignore certain columns such as ID = "1" & "2"

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to query my Mysql table to return certain rows. I have it set up to show every row in the table, however I would like it to not display the rows with ID = 1 ID = 2 ID = 3.

Here is my search.php that's used to query the database.

```
<?php
$responce = "Please enter a search term";
        if(!isset($_POST['searchterm'])) {
        ?>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white"><u><?php echo $responce;?></u></h3><?php
    }


    $names = array();
    $link = array();


    if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])) {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Password");
        mysql_select_db("videos");
        $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));


        $find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos)) {
            $names[] = $row['name'];
            $link[] = $row['link'];
        }

    }
    $deletethen = "DELETE  FROM videos WHERE name = ''";

    include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 125% }
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Network TV | search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/3.1.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background:center no-repeat fixed url('images/bg.jpg'); background-size: cover;overflow-x: hidden; background-color: black">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Network TV</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
        <section style="padding-top:100px; width:100%"class="container-fluid" id="section2">
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="color:white">Network TV</h1>
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white"><u>Search results</u></h3>




                                        <table align="center" class="table" style="color: white; width:50%">
                                                <thead>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <?php
                                                        $i=0;
                                                        foreach($names as $name) {
                                                         echo '<tr>
                                                              <td><h4>' . $name . '</h4></td>
                                                              <td><a href="' .$link[$i]. '"><strong><h4><u>Watch now!</u></h4></strong></a></td></tr>';
                                                        $i++;
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
        </section>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is archaic. See about modern APIs (PDO,mysqli) and prepared statements. And change your password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id NOT IN(1,2,3)`

That should do the trick.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot you can combine them...facepalm...

Comment: I need to add your bit of code onto my existing query. $find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'"); how do i do that?

Comment: @OliverKetley `$find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE keywords LIKE'%$search%' AND id NOT IN(1,2,3)");`

Comment: Thank You that's working perfectly, such a simple fix, cannot believe i could not figure it out.